# Refresh all String Resources when Culture Changed

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

I've written a WPF app in which user can change culture. The Method in app.xaml.cs looks like this :

```
public void SelectCulture(string culture)
{
        // List all our resources      
        List<ResourceDictionary> dictionaryList = new List<ResourceDictionary>();
        foreach (ResourceDictionary dictionary in Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries)
        {
            dictionaryList.Add(dictionary);
        }
        // We want our specific culture      
        string requestedCulture = string.Format("Resources/StringResources.{0}.xaml", culture);
        ResourceDictionary resourceDictionary = dictionaryList.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Source.OriginalString == requestedCulture);

        if (resourceDictionary == null)
        {
            // If not found, we select our default language        
            //        
            requestedCulture = "Resources/StringResources.en-ES.xaml";
            resourceDictionary = dictionaryList.FirstOrDefault(d => d.Source.OriginalString == requestedCulture);
        }

        // If we have the requested resource, remove it from the list and place at the end.\      
        // Then this language will be our string table to use.      
        if (resourceDictionary != null)
        {
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Remove(resourceDictionary);
            Application.Current.Resources.MergedDictionaries.Add(resourceDictionary);
        }

        // Inform the threads of the new culture      
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(culture);
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = new CultureInfo(culture);
}
```

This allows to change on runtime every string resources from different resourcedictionnary.

But not every resources: those which are used in xaml via `DynamicResource` like this :

```
<GroupBox Header="{DynamicResource RootSettings}" >
```

are correctly updated.

But those which are used in C# code like in ViewModel like this :

```
stTestConnection = System.Windows.Application.Current.Resources["Connectionsucceded"].ToString();
```

do not update.

All string Resources are declared in different resources dictionaries like this :

```
<ResourceDictionary xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
                    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" xmlns:system="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib">
    
    <!-- #region Global -->
    <system:String x:Key="CriticalErrorTitle">Critical Error</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="ErrorTitle">Error</system:String>
    <system:String x:Key="CloseApp">Application will close</system:String>
```

Any idea why the string resources used in C# are not updating but the ones used in XAML are ?

Ask me if more info needed.

Thanks

Comment: Have you implemented a mechanism to reset the values filled by C# code?

Comment: No. I mean all string values declared in resourcesdictionnaries that are used in C# don't refresh in the view. But the values used in xaml directly are. But you suggest that such mechanism would reset values in all application classes ?

Comment: Exactly. In Xaml, the WPF system will care for resetting because it is DynamicResource but for code implemented in C#, you need to somehow manage resetting on your own.

Comment: Also, be sure that your use case truly requires this dynamic functionality.  I say this only because I once wasted great deal of time trying for the same thing only to realize it was completely unnecessary:  In my application, forcing the user to restart after changing the language was a perfectly valid restriction, because it's typically something the user *does once and then never again*.    Obviously your needs may vary but be sure you aren't chasing an unnecessary convenience.

Comment: @emoacht I don't know about such mechanism. I need to implement it myself ? At first sight it seems to be an enormous amount of work. I have C#side string resources used in more than 8 classes ... Despite, the event culture changed is triggered on MainWindow side but none of my ViewModels have access to MainVM nor the opposite ..

Comment: @Joe thank you for advice. To be honest, it is more of a POC than a requirement. But i wanted it to be possible

Answer (score 0):

I had to do something similar recently with a runtime theme change performing a colour change using Xamarin in c#.

If I remember correctly then in Xaml with DynaminResource they updated automatically. But when in came to the c# code I had to do so manually. This was triggered by a xamarin OnThemeChanged.

If you have access to a similar method during culture change, you could put all your update logic there.

Comment: Thank you for answer. Sadly i don't know any WPF equivalent of the Xamarin method you are refering to. I'll look a it though.